# My mysql container in Docker, via the feature I gave it from the dockerfile to restart itself, keeps turning itself on and off

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My mysql container in docker, via the feature I gave it from the dockerfile to restart itself, keeps turning itself on and off after I attempted the `docker-compose up --build` command.

My Dockerfile contains several containers, including an apache, a mysql with a volume to save the data of a database and a php.

I ran into this problem as I was carrying out various tests since I had just created the volume and I wanted to see if the database was not losing the data inside it.

After various commands of `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` it happened that the mysql container did not work anymore, not even after other commands `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose build --no-cache`.

> below i added my docker.compose.yml

> all versions of the images and data for the database are taken from the various dockerfiles

---

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  php:
   build: 
    context: './php/'
    args:
     PHP_VERSION: ${PHP_VERSION}
   networks:
    - backend
   volumes:
    - ${PROJECT_ROOT}/:/var/www/html/
   container_name: php
apache:
  build:
    context: './apache/'
    args:
     APACHE_VERSION: ${APACHE_VERSION}
  depends_on:
    - php
    - mysql
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ${PROJECT_ROOT}/:/var/www/html/
  container_name: apache
mysql:
  image: mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION:-latest}
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
        - data:/var/lib/mysql
  networks:
    - backend
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_NAME}"
    MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
  container_name: mysql   networks:
  frontend:
   backend:
  volumes:
   data:
```

---

**Anyone can describe me what I can do in this case in order not to lose the progress made so far within the database since doing a little research they tell me that the volume and the image of mysql may have been corrupted?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question and provide more details, at least about your `docker-compose.yml` specification. Otherwise (without a [mre]), it is impossible for people to answer your question.

Comment: hi, I added various information and reworded the question to make the question more precise

Comment: Thanks! but you said "the mysql container does not work anymore", so can you be more specific, e.g. you may also want to add excerpts of the logs for the service at stake? (`docker-compose logs mysql`)

Comment: the problem, as said in the explanation before the question is: my container with mysql image no longer works.
 
The problem, looking on the internet it seems to be the corrupt image or container so there is no other solution but to delete this container and rebuild it. I asked if there was a way to save the database I created inside the mysql container so as not to lose the data inside.

Comment: OK… regarding what you say: (i) that something "no longer works" is not precise enough, hence my question to share more details about the logs, (ii) "a corrupt image or container" does not seem plausible with Docker/docker-compose, the closer symptom one can have is a permission problem (if you use so-called bind mounts), (iii) given you have created a named volume `data:/var/lib/mysql` (which is a very good point), mysql's data is stored there, so there should be no risk to remove/recreate the container, which can be do by running `docker-compose down` then `docker-compose up -d` for example.

Comment: Note also that you can always run [`docker-compose exec mysql /bin/bash`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/) to enter your Compose service container and inspect/fix things…